# SecurityFilterChain .anyRequest().permitAll() doesn't allow POST requests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Using Spring Boot 2.7 (Spring Security 5.7.1) and trying to configure an API as a resource server and OAuth2 client I find a behavior I don't get to understand:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .mvcMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())

                // register OAuth2 resource server
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)

                // register OAuth2 client
                .oauth2Client(withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Checking the logs, all this filters apply

```
o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with 

org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@320ca97c,
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3c592c0c,
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2b33e616,
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2e9bff08,
org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@7926d092,
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@37227aa7,
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@6f18445b,
org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@42af2977,
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@79e3f444, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1252d480,
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3979c6e8,
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter@19faa9dc,
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7d3b4646,
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6cb2d5ea,
```

So far, this configuration works as expected in the other APIs I'm protecting. However, in this particular one, AND not having protected any endpoint I see that:

I can access any `GET` endpoint but any `POST` endpoint returns a `403 FORBIDDEN`. However, I can access them if I add a token to the request **EVEN if its an expired token**

This alone I can't understand as `.anyRequest().permitAll()` should unprotect anything, if I'm not wrong.

If I comment out the line configuring the oauth2 ResourceServer

```
`// .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)`
```

this filter dissapears

`org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter`

And can't use `POST` endpoints anymore, even with the expired token

Logically, I want the API to be `oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)` so

How it is I can't access POST endpoints when using `.anyRequest().permitAll())`?

**DISCLAIMER**: I know it makes no sense to declare the API as resource server if all endpoints must be public. Endpoints will be accessed by Discord callbacks and I have to figure out if I can protect them with OAuth

**EDIT:**

```
server.servlet.context-path = /api
```

### Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/slack")
public class SlackBotController {
    @PostMapping("/test")
    public String test(@RequestBody String a) {
        return a;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String testGet() {
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

### Request

```
GET/POST http://localhost:8081/api/slack/test
```

#### Request headers

```
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: f20ba7a6-26e5-47c4-a827-0596afec27b8
Host: localhost:8081
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 3
Cookie: JSESSIONID=D1C2B2668DC130C63DDE03F30574ED5F; JSESSIONID=823D79956CFBF14F3C77C96E29F4131C
```

#### Response headers

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 03 Jun 2022 12:03:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Can you show an example of url you are trying to make POST request to?

Comment: Sure, there it is @AndreyGrigoriev

Comment: disable csrf by `http.csrf().disable()` otherwise u need to provide extra information in your post header or basically on all modifying requests.

Comment: Checked your case in a sample project, it works. Maybe something wrong with your auth server configuration. By the way - it's a very strange case when you have both client and resource server in the same application

Comment: @DanielWosch thank you. CSRF was the issue. I tried with CORS but didn't think of CSRF.

Comment: @AndreyGrigoriev is an API which makes use of a bunch of other services (REST APIs as well) Am I missing something? I would you implement that?

Comment: If the client is for other services, then it's OK. Seems like I got you wrong

Comment: @DanielWosch would you mind to formulate your comment as a response?

Comment: @luso sure :) - done

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason why the `POST` endpoint or the `POST` returns a `403 FORBIDDEN` because the CSRF protection is enabled by default in spring.

That means that every **modifying** request (*POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH*) requires a CSRF token. Otherwise the request gets denied to prevent CSRF attacks.

To disable the CSRF protection:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but disabling the CSRF protection is not the right thing to do because when using `oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)` Spring Security configures itself to not require CSRF token on requests that contain `Authorization: Bearer ...`

Comment: Sure but as I understand correctly he requires a POST endpoint without providing the specific Bearer header

Comment: Disabling CSRF exposes you to the vulnerability, the best option would be to provide a csrf token in this case

Comment: Thank you for both your comments. @MarcusHertdaCoregio this public endpoints are callback URLs for 3rd party applications (slack/discord bots for example) I'm not sure I can add a token there, but I'll definitively taking a look. Thanks again

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio sure. you are right. That’s why it’s enabled per default since some spring version but as the OP said that’s (currently) the only way due to this requirements. So we are both right in some way :P

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the CSRF protection. When you use `http.oauth2ResourceServer()` Spring Security configures CSRF to ignore requests that contains the header `Authorization: Bearer whatever`, note that it has to contain the `Bearer`  prefix.

In the request sample that you shared, you are not including the Authorization header.

Take a look [at the code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/a3e996a66bd5b9f12b52d83d9babc6bd5bb8b22f/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/server/resource/OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.java#L329) in Spring Security.

Comment: I guess you mean "to ignore requests that DOESN'T contain" right? In any case, requests matching the permitAll() should be accepted without a token, right?

Comment: No, I really meant it. If you look at the code that I shared the CSRF protection will not trigger if the request contains the `Authorizarion: Bearer ...` header. That makes sense since the authentication scheme in this scenario is token-based instead of cookie-based

Comment: `permitAll()` doesn't mean that the CSRF protection will not trigger, it's a valid scenario to have a public endpoint but still require CSRF

Comment: I now get what you mean. Is the CSRF **protection** which ignores the requests